# NextJS error on creating FormData POST request in api

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am trying to make a create FormData to submit as a POST within NextJs api route

**Dir: /pages/api/file.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const formdata = new FormData()
  ....
```

Can someone please explain why this throws the error:

> ReferenceError: FormData is not defined

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you share more code?